# "outer" in python similar to Mathematica

Tags: python-3.x, wolfram-mathematica, outer-join

I have an array of 2D positions (x,y) of a few particles. In Mathematica, I can use 
    `Outer[Subtract, pos, pos, 1]`
If `pos` is an array of shape `(n,2)` where `n` is the number of particles, the result of the above Mathematia code is a `n x n x 2` array and each [i,j] element of this matrix is the result of `(x_i - x_j, y_i - y_j)` operation.

For example

```
pos = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
Outer[Subtract, pos, pos, 1]
```

gives

```
{
 {{0, 0}, {x1 - x2, y1 - y2}, {x1 - x3, y1 - y3}}
 ,
 {{-x1 + x2, -y1 + y2}, {0, 0}, {x2 - x3, y2 - y3}}
 ,
 {{-x1 + x3, -y1 + y3}, {-x2 + x3, -y2 + y3}, {0, 0}}
}
```

which is a 3x3x2 array. However, in python I could not get similar results:

```
import numpy as np
pos = [[1, 2], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
print (np.subtract.outer(pos, pos).shape)
```

gives `(3, 2, 3, 2)`, and `np.subtract.outer(pos, pos)` is

```
array([[[[ 0, -1],
     [-4, -5],
     [-7, -8]],

    [[ 1,  0],
     [-3, -4],
     [-6, -7]]],


   [[[ 4,  3],
     [ 0, -1],
     [-3, -4]],

    [[ 5,  4],
     [ 1,  0],
     [-2, -3]]],


   [[[ 7,  6],
     [ 3,  2],
     [ 0, -1]],

    [[ 8,  7],
     [ 4,  3],
     [ 1,  0]]]])
```

while for similar values the Mathemtica code gives what I need, that is

```
{
{{0, 0}, {-4, -4}, {-7, -7}}
,
{{4, 4}, {0, 0}, {-3, -3}}
, 
{{7, 7}, {3, 3}, {0, 0}}
}
```

Comment: does this solve your problem? `np.squeeze([i-pos for i in np.array(pos)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for:

```
pos = np.array(pos)

pos[:,None]-pos
```

You can also achieve the same by:

```
np.squeeze([i-pos for i in pos])
```

EDIT:

For normalization, you can do:

```
ss = np.linalg.norm(pos_diff,axis = 2,keepdims = True)
ss[ss==0] = 1

pos_diff/ss
```

Comment: yes, but how the trick `pos[:,None]-pos` works. How does python recognize to do subtract 2d elements?

Comment: @Fluid this is a technique referred to as broadcasting. You can google broadcasting in python.

Comment: thank you very much. I have one more question below about dividing 2D vectors (elements of `pos[:,None]-pos`) by the norm of the 2D vectors. I wrote the question in details below in the answers section.

Comment: what is `aa`?? I cant figure out how you came up with `pos_norm` also

Comment: I fixed it. instead of `aa` it should be `pos_diff`

Comment: @Fluid I see okay, so if aa is pos_diff, then you can do something like: `np.squeeze([i/j[:,None] for i,j in zip(aa,np.identity(3)+pos_norm)])`

Comment: thank you for the solution. This code `pos_diff / np.outer(pos_norm+np.identity(3),np.array([1,1])).reshape(3,3,2)` does the trick too, but I am looking for a solution that takes advantage of list operations rather than element-wie operations, something similar to your beautiful solution `pos[:,None]-pos` for the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.ufunc.outer(a,b)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) will calculate each possible combination with one element from `a` and another from `b`. One option is to carry out calculations for the x and y coordinates separately and then remerge the `result`:

```
pos = np.array([[1, 2], [5, 7], [8, 13]])
dx = np.subtract.outer(pos[:,0],pos[:,0])
dy = np.subtract.outer(pos[:,1],pos[:,1])
result=np.transpose([dx,dy], axes=(1,2,0))
```

(I changed the values in `pos` so that the result is less symmetric.)

Edit: As compared to calculating and storing useless x_i-y_j by acting `subtract.outer` on the whole arrays then using `squeeze` afterwards, this solution is significantly more effective for large arrays.